# How to integrate Stripe payment without redirects - Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have my stripe payment up and working. However I am wanting the user to be able to make the payment without leaving the page they are on.

Is it possible to submit a Stripe Payment using Django without redirecting?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your integration and why there is currently a redirect? This would seem to be something that would be an implementation detail, as it is not a requirement of the Stripe API/client.

Answer (score 0):

https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

I read the docs and think you can do it

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_123"

stripe.Charge.create(
  amount=2000,
  currency="usd",
  source="tok_amex", # obtained with Stripe.js
  metadata={'order_id': '6735'}
)

{
  "id": "ch_1IQDpm2eZvKYlo2CiLKj2hKU",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 100,
  "amount_captured": 0,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_1032HU2eZvKYlo2CEPtcnUvl",
  "billing_details": {
    "address": {
      "city": null,
      "country": null,
      "line1": null,
      "line2": null,
      "postal_code": null,
      "state": null
    },
    "email": null,
    "name": "Jenny Rosen",
    "phone": null
  },
  "calculated_statement_descriptor": null,
  "captured": false,
  "created": 1614613138,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "description": "My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
  "disputed": false,
  "failure_code": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "fraud_details": {},
  "invoice": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
    "order_id": "6735"
  },
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "order": null,
  "outcome": null,
  "paid": true,
  "payment_intent": null,
  "payment_method": "card_19yUNL2eZvKYlo2CNGsN6EWH",
  "payment_method_details": {
    "card": {
      "brand": "visa",
      "checks": {
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_postal_code_check": null,
        "cvc_check": "unchecked"
      },
      "country": "US",
      "exp_month": 12,
      "exp_year": 2020,
      "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
      "funding": "credit",
      "installments": null,
      "last4": "4242",
      "network": "visa",
      "three_d_secure": null,
      "wallet": null
    },
    "type": "card"
  },
  "receipt_email": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1032D82eZvKYlo2C/ch_1IQDpm2eZvKYlo2CiLKj2hKU/rcpt_J2IQ7elQ2RfOD61BRlasDqCLV5ErY2f",
  "refunded": false,
  "refunds": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1IQDpm2eZvKYlo2CiLKj2hKU/refunds"
  },
  "review": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source_transfer": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}
```